# Convergence in $L^p$, Cauchy in $L^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

If $u_n$ is a convergent sequence in $L^p$ with $u_n \to u$, and $u_n$ is convergent is $L^\infty$, is it true that the limit in $L^\infty$ must be $u$? Is it true if $u_n$ are all test functions, i.e. compact support and $C^\infty$?

I am trying to understand this in order to understand an approximation argument in the Sobolev space $W^{1,\ p}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Yes. Think of a subsequence converging a.e.

Comment: so convergence in $L^p$ implies there exists subsequence $u_{n_k}$ converging pointwise a.e. to $u$, and convergence in $L^\infty$ implies $u_{n_k}$ converges uniformly (and hence pointwise) a.e. to some $v$, so that $v = u$ a.e.?

Comment: Yes, this works. You can post an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So convergence in $L^p$ implies there exists subsequence $\{u_{n_k}\}$ converging pointwise a.e. to $u$, and convergence in $L^\infty$ implies $\{u_{n_k}\}$ converges uniformly (and hence pointwise) a.e. to some $v$, so that $v=u$ a.e.